How do I create a simple yes-no countplot (Pandas)?
I am trying to create a simple countplot giving a count for a yes-no statistics.
However what do I get is y axis between 0 and 1 and not giving an actual count of the variable (re-scalling the axis did not work). Then the count is listed on the x axis.
I just don't know how to fix this simple issue:-D Please help me >.>
dict = {"Condition": ['no','yes'], "Smoking":[1561,635]}
frame=pd.DataFrame(data=dict)
frame.set_index("Condition", inplace=True)
frame

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
sns.set_palette("pastel", 8)

sns.countplot(data=frame,  x="Smoking" )

plt.show()


Side note: it is ill-advised to call a dictionary dict (same with list, etc.). Doing so, overwrites python's built-in dict. E.g., if later on in your code, you would want to do this: dict(key='value'), you'll bump into a TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable.

The original dictionary structure wasn't suitable for a countplot. Seaborn's countplot function expects each row to represent an individual observation, not pre-aggregated data
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


data = {"Smoking": ["no", "yes"],
        "Count": [1561, 635]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.set_palette("pastel")

sns.barplot(data=df, x="Smoking", y="Count")

plt.title("Smoking Status Count")
plt.xlabel("Smoking Status")
plt.ylabel("Count")

plt.show()



Just to add to this for the OP's benefit. To achieve this result with sns.countplot, one would expect df to look like this: df = pd.DataFrame({'Smoking': np.repeat(['no','yes'], [1561,635])}). So, what is referred to here as "pre-aggregated data". With a df like this, you can do sns.countplot(data=df, x='Smoking') to get the same result.

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dict = {"Condition": ['no', 'yes'], "Smoking": [1561, 635]}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data=dict)

# Plotting the bar plot
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
sns.set_palette("pastel", 8)

# Use barplot 
sns.barplot(data=frame, x="Condition", y="Smoking")

# Show the plot
plt.show()


